# Usar componente .NET en aplicacion COM+

Tags: c#, asp, interop, vb6

En mi empresa hay una aplicación `asp` que interactúa con componentes COM+ hechos en `Visual Basic 6` y uno de esos componentes COM+ interactúa con un componente hecho con .NET C#, para lo cual se tuvo que crear la librería de tipos (tlb) para el componente .NET y agregarlo como referencia en VB6. En VB6 para ese componente está configurada la compatibilidad binaria. Tenemos servidor de pruebas y servidor de producción. Recientemente tuve que realizar un ajuste al componente COM+ y al componente .NET C#, y colocándolos en el servidor de pruebas, funcionó bien, se realizaron diversas pruebas exitosas. Sin embargo, cuando se liberó al ambiente de producción, el componente COM+ me lanza un error de excepción:

> Componente ActiveX no puede crear el objeto.

No entiendo por qué el error ya que el componente COM+  está registrado mediante `RegSvr32` en ambos ambientes y tanto el DLL como el TLB de .NET están disponibles en la misma ruta del COM+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo mas probable es que la causa del error sea el registro del componente desarrollado en .NET

Que yo recuerde, estos componentes se registran utilizando la utilidad [Regasm.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx) y es al usar esta utilidad cuando se genera el archivo `TLB` que es el que importarás desde VB6 (yo lo hacía desde Delphi)

Además tu clase de .NET debe estar decorada con el atributo [`ComVisible`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute(v=vs.100).aspx) y también tienes que tener este atributo a nivel de ensamblado.

El componente .NET también se podría implementar heredando de [ServicedComponent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.enterpriseservices.servicedcomponent(v=vs.110).aspx), en ese caso la utilidad para registrarlo es [Regsvcs.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/04za0hca(v=vs.110).aspx)

Dos trucos que evitan muchos problemas son:

- Crear un interfaz por defecto para el objeto que queremos que sea visible para COM (esto evita que te genere un interfaz automáticamente que es difícil controlar)
- Asignar GUIDs específicos tanto al Interfaz como para la clase (con esto evitas que a la hora de registarlo se asigne un GUID distinto al que has referenciado desde VB6)

La implementación quedaría algo así:

```
[ComVisible(true), Guid("AF2FD61E-0BD6-4217-852A-236D3376CB60")]
public interface IMiObjetoCOM
{
    ..
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("F64CD35B-43AF-4EFE-93ED-D5A5522CD1A4")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MiObjetoCom: IMyObjetoCOM
{
    ..
}
```

Comment: rsciriano, hice conforme a tu propuesta y tampoco, me genera el mismo error, yo cuando genero un ensamblado uso la herramienta regasm para exportar la libreria de tipos que luego pongo como referencia en VB6. Yo veo el problema como en otro aspecto porque como decía inicialmente, en ambiente de pruebas que es un espejo del ambiente de producción, los componentes funcionan bien, pero ya en producción hay problemas.

Comment: @user2403459 La herramienta Regasm.exe también la tienes que utilizar en producción porque es la que registra el componente de .NET ¿Como lo estás registrando en producción? ¿Con la TLB?

Comment: Si, yo solamente estoy generando el TLB en mi ambiente de desarrollo. Debo usar regasm para registrarla en produccion?

Comment: No, tienes que utilizar `Regasm.exe` también en producción porque añade la información al registro de donde está en ensamblado de .NET, con la TLB solo añade las clases e interfaces

Comment: rsciriano, excelente!!! muchisimas gracias, tenias razón, el componente ya ejecutó en producción, faltaba registrarlo. Muchas gracias.